# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with special deliminators

Tags: mysql, delimiter, load-data-infile, number-with-delimiter

I have data that has fields deliminated by `\u0001` and records deliminated by `\u0002\n`. I want to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import all of the data at once into a MySQL database. I know that `\u0001` can be written as `X'01'`, but I am not sure how to write `\u0002\n'.

This is what I have so far.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE my_table 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'01'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (col1, col2, col3);
```

The above SQL statement works but I'm afraid that the `\u0002` might be imported into the database along with the data.

I know that `\u0002` can be written as `X'02'` but I'm not too sure how I can combine `X'02'` with `\n`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: huh, my suggestion is go with your current method, then do a replacement of `\u00002` after the import is completed (so, you don't have to wait for perfect solution)

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are trying to implement iTunes EPF :), 
`X'01'` + `'\n'` =>  `X'020a'`
So your query can be written as:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE my_table 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'01'
    LINES TERMINATED BY X'020a'
    (col1, col2, col3);
```

If you are really working on implementing an iTunes EPF integration, you can use next query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<path to your file>' INTO TABLE `<table name>` CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'01' LINES TERMINATED BY X'020a' IGNORE 34 LINES;
```

Such as apple provide text data in 4-byte UTF8 which can be stored in MySQL just with UTF8MB4 charset (I mean to correct port all text records).
First 34 lines will be ignored ( as should — its is 'legal policy' data).
and need to remove last line from file. (I remove it with script before porting)

Hopes it helps someone.